# An algebraic solution for $\log_3(x+1)+\log_2(x)=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The logarithmic equation

$$\log_3(x+1)+\log_2(x)=5$$

has an obvious solution, namely $x=8$. However, I can't seen to find an algebraic demonstration/deduction of this fact. This has been an "unsolvable" problem for me since my early days in elementary/middle school. Any solution not relying on inspection would be appreciated.

EDIT: Driven by @TobyMak's comments: The main issue here is that this problem was supposed to be solved by a middle school student. Using analysis and knowing beforehand that $x=8$ solves the equation does the job. I would like to know if there are finite algebraic steps which lead to the result.

Comment: An “algebraic demonstration” that $x=8$ is a solution consists of plugging in $8$ for $x$ and verifying that you get an equality.

Comment: For $x > 0$ the function is monotonically increasing, so there is only one solution.  But you need an 'algebra-precalculus' solution, right?

Comment: That the truth or falsity (in this case truth) is easily for verified $x=8$ is a consequence of the fact that $8=2^3$ ($2$ raised to a rational power), and $8+1=3^2$ ($3$ raised to a rational power). If you change the RHS to any positive integer other than $2$ or $5$, I doubt that the solution (though it exists) can be expressed as an elementary numerical expression. Thus, my sense is that in all likelihood, there is no symbolic way of solving your equation other than by inspection.

Comment: "I would like to know if there are finite algebraic steps which lead to the result". The steps are to try some small numbers or guess the solution, and then show it is the only one since logarithm is monotonically increasing. I've once encountered $x^{x^3}=3$ on a high school olympiad and wanted to know how to arrive at the single result, but there was no way other then correctly guessing it (this one could be transformed to $y^y=3^3$ allowing for guessing $y=3$ and in turn $x=3^{1/3}$, in your case it is simple since you don't need any substitution to guess the integer solution)

Comment: @Aquerman Kuczmenda: As I suggested in my previous comment, my guess is that for any fixed positive integer $n$ other than $n=2$ or $n=5$, the unique positive real value of $x$ such that 
$$\log_3(x+1)+\log_2(x)=n$$
can't be expressed as an elementary numerical expression. But a proof that no such representation is possible will typically employ very advanced methods (e.g., Differential Galois Theory).

Comment: @quasi This would not be an answer to this question but I would very much like to see such approach!

Comment: @Aquerman Kuczmenda: Perhaps someone else can answer more authoritatively, but as far as I'm aware, for a given class of equations, if it's been proved that the solutions can't be expressed as elementary numerical expressions, then any such known proof leverages some form of Galois Theory.

Comment: @Aquerman Kuczmenda: Simple example: How does one show that there is no finite sequence of algebraic operations (allowing addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, radicals, and rational constants) to find the unique real solution to the equation $x^5+x=3$? Answer: Galois Theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log_3(x+1)+\log_2 x=5$$

$$\log_3(x+1)=5-\log_2 x$$

$$x+1=3^{5-\log_2 x}$$

For integer solutions for x we must have:

$$5-\log_2 x>0$$

⇒ $$\log_2 x<5$$

Therefore we must check numbers 4, 3,2, 1 which gives:

$\log_2 x= 1, 2, 3, 4$

⇒$x=2, 4, 8, 16$

These solution must also satisfy the initial equation; corresponding values are:

$\log_3 (x+1)=5-\log_2x=5-1=4,5-2= 3,5-3= 2,5-4= 1$

⇒ $x+1= 3^4=81, 3^3=27, 3^2=9, 3^1=3$

⇒$x= 80, 26, 8, 2$

The only common solution is 8.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=\log_3(x+1)+\log_2x.$

Thus, since $f$ increases, our equation has one root maximum.

$8$ is a root, which says that it's an unique root and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to think of how a middle schooler might solve this:

Let $x=2^a$.  Then we have

$$\log_3 (2^a+1) + a = 5.$$ So that

$$2^a+1 = 3^{5-a}.$$

Multiply by $3^a$ to get

$$6^a+3^a = 3^5 = 243.$$

If the student knows that $6^3 = 216,$  he knows that $a$ is pretty close to $3$, which does in fact work, giving $x=8.$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but I hope it helps.

$\log_2(x)=a$ means that $2^a=x$

$\log_3(x+1)=b$ means that $3^b=x+1$

To get $a+b=5$ where $3^b$ is after $2^a$ by $+1$ only (somehow consecutive numbers), then it is most likely that $a$ and $b$ are integers. (This step isn't reasonable actually, it is just "looks like so")

Now if $a$ and $b$ are integers, the ofcourse $x$ is also an integer, so now you'll be searching for $2$ consecutive numbers where the first is a power of $2$ and the second is a power of $3$, and there is the condition that $a+b=5$ so if you start trying natural numbers, the first 2 numbers that satisfy the above conditions are $8=2^3$ and $9=3^2$, and $2+3=5$, so your only answer is $x=8$.